# Why importing files from App/src is throwing error in the IDE but compiles fine?

Tags: angular

why all imports starting with src/app/ shows cannot be found error but the application compiles successfully and doesn't show any error in the compiler. Should i Add something in the tsconfig file?
I Do not understand the issue, why VScode is not able to trap this issue and it compiles perfectly and application is also running smoothly... Can somebody help. Thanks
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN21k.png)

Comment: Do you have an eslint file? If yes, what is its content?

Comment: "root": true,
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "src/**/*.test.ts",
    "projects/**/*",
    "src/frontend/generated/*",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Having `src` in your module specifiers is almost certainly a bug.